# R: function that generates first n terms

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function that would generate first n terms with the given equation.
For example: f(x_2)= x_1*r+3, and x_n = f(x_(n-1)
Here is my code:

```
super = function(x,r,n){
x[n] = r*x+3
x1=seq(x,x[n],,n)
return(x1)
}
```

When I try to run it I keep getting: Error in super(0.6, 2, 100) : could not find function "x".
But if I make a basic code like:

```
n=88
x=0.6
x1 = seq(x,100,,n)
```

everything works

Thanks in advance for any inputs

Comment: Are you sure that's the error message you are getting with the code above? I cannot reproduce that error. Instead i get `Error in seq.default(x, x[n], , n) : 'from' must be of length 1`

Comment: I only do get your error message if i change second line to

    x[n] = r*x[n-1]+3
logically that is how it is supposed to be, but I can't figure out how to tell R to run the function n times starting with provided x

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can try using `x1=seq(x[1],x[n],,n)` instead

Comment: I don't think it changes much, since i provide x[1], but I just call it x. And if I just switch x with x[1] in the first and third line it starts giving me errors after each line saying i have unexpected } and etc.

Comment: Your problem is recursive -- either solve for the closed form in terms of n (which is obvious in your example) or define the function once as `r <- 5; function(x) r*x+3` and find the terms in a loop `xseq <- rep(NA,n); xseq[1] <- 1; for (i in 2:n) xseq[i] <- f(xseq[i-1])`.

Answer (score 0):

We can slice the input and apply function on the new slice.

```
getFirstN = function(arr, func, n){
    slice = arr[1:n]
    return(lapply(slice, func))
}
e.g.:
square = function(x) {
    return(x * x)
}

example = c(1, 2, 3, 4)

print(getFirstN(example, square, 2)) 
1, 4 # the output
```